# Single maximum quasiconcave

Tags: optimization

Let $f(x)$ a positive decreasing real function with a positive domain. If $(1/f)$ is convex, is it true that $h(x)=xf(x)$ has a unique maximum?

Comment: No, take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: What are the properties we need of $f(x)$ so $h(x)$ is strictly quasi-concave.